# Show prompt only on form submit

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

I'm using Position Absolute validation engine but wants validation only on form submit.

How can I do that?

[Here's the link I've found this library](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)

Comment: by form submit I meant click on Submit button

Answer (score 1):

Solved this with:

$('#form_id').validationEngine({validationEventTrigger: 'submit'});